# load custom review attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, model, review

I'm using magento 1.9.2.4 version.
I tried to add custom field(file) in product review page. I have added new attribute to `review_detail` table using

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('review_detail')} 
    ADD COLUMN(customfield' varchar(255) NULL);
```

Now added the field in `review_detail` table. Now i'm trying to add/save the data with `customfield` using my custom module `review_save_before` event by calling `myFunction`.
When printing the model, it does not added my custom field.

`MyFunction` code is here

```
public function myFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    $data = $object->getData();
    $review = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()->getData();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    exit;
}
```

How to assign and save data for my `customfield` using the model.

**Updates**:
Config.xml

```
<models>
    <customreview>
        <class>Mycompany_Customreview_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customreview_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </customreview>
    <customreview_mysql4>
        <class>Mycompany_Customreview_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <customreview><table>review_detail</table></customreview>
        </entities>
        <rewrite>
            <review>Mycompany_Customreview_Model_Resource_Review</review>
        </rewrite>
    </customreview_mysql4>
</models>
<resources>
    <customreview_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Mycompany_Customreview</module>
            <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </customreview_setup>
    <customreview_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </customreview_write>
    <customreview_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </customreview_read>
</resources>

<review_save_after>
    <observers>
        <add_custom_field_to_the_review>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>customreview/observer</class>
            <method>myFunction</method>
        </add_custom_field_to_the_review>
    </observers>
</review_save_after>
```

**In installer script:**

```
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('review/review_detail'),'customfield', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'length'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'Custom Field'
    ));
```

**In my phtml file:**

```
<li>
    <label for="customfield" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Custom Field') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <textarea name="customfield" id="customfield" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getCustomfield()) ?></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

**My observer:**

```
public function myFunction($observer)
{
    $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    if (!$object->getCustomfield()) {
        echo "nop";exit;
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        /** @var Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface $connection */
        $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $reviewDetailTable = $adapter->getTableName('review_detail');
        $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($reviewDetailTable, 'detail_id')
            ->where('review_id = :review_id');
        $detailId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, array(':review_id' => $object->getId()));

        if ($detailId) {
            $detail = array(
                'customfield' => $object->getCustomfield()
            );
            $condition = array("detail_id = ?" => $detailId);
            $adapter->update($reviewDetailTable, $detail, $condition);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Data is saved to the table `review/review_detail` with different method. There are 3 fields in the resource model:

1. **title**
2. **detail**
3. **nickname**

They are saved manually to this table. Other data is ignored whether it present in the `review` model or not. Here is a part of code responsible for that:

```
/**
 * Perform actions after object save
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 * @return Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review
 */
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    /**
     * save detail
     */
    $detail = array(
        'title' => $object->getTitle(),
        'detail' => $object->getDetail(),
        'nickname' => $object->getNickname(),
    );
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->_reviewDetailTable, 'detail_id')
        ->where('review_id = :review_id');
    $detailId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, array(':review_id' => $object->getId()));

    if ($detailId) {
        $condition = array("detail_id = ?" => $detailId);
        $adapter->update($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail, $condition);
    } else {
        $detail['store_id'] = $object->getStoreId();
        $detail['customer_id'] = $object->getCustomerId();
        $detail['review_id'] = $object->getId();
        $adapter->insert($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail);
    }
```

You have several options:

1. You can save your data in the table `review/review` and not in the table `review/review_detail`.
2. You can write an observer to add necessary data after saving all the review objects (`save_after`) and save again.

I suppose, that the first option is better. All you need to realize it is to add your field to the table `review/review`. After that all data will be saved automatically without an observer.

If you choose the second option, you should rewrite your observer in the following way:

Use the event `review_save_after` in the `config.xml` file:

```
<events>
    <review_save_after>
        <observers>
            <add_custom_field_to_the_review>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>test/observer</class>
                <method>myFunction</method>
            </add_custom_field_to_the_review>
        </observers>
    </review_save_after>
```

Do the following changes in your method:

```
public function myFunction($observer)
{
    $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    if (!$object->getCustomfield()) {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        /** @var Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface $connection */
        $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $reviewDetailTable = $adapter->getTableName('review_detail');
        $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($reviewDetailTable, 'detail_id')
            ->where('review_id = :review_id');
        $detailId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, array(':review_id' => $object->getId()));

        if ($detailId) {
            $detail = array(
                'customfield' => $object->getCustomfield()
            );
            $condition = array("detail_id = ?" => $detailId);
            $adapter->update($reviewDetailTable, $detail, $condition);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This allows to successfully save data to the table review_details.

[image]

We checked this by adding the input form to the products review.

```
<li>
    <label for="customfield" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Custom Field') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <textarea name="customfield" id="customfield" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($data->getCustomfield()) ?></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image]

Additionally, we recommend you to update your installation script:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('review/review_detail'),'customfield', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'length'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'Custom Field'
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Magework. I have tried with both `review` and `review_detail` method. But both of the methods not working for me. when i printed `$object->getCustomfield()` returns empty.

Comment: @SaravananDS Can you please update your question with the current code? It should help us understand how and where you try get data. Most probably, something is missing, because everything works in our case for both described options.

Comment: @Magework I have updated with my code. Please check my updates.

Comment: @SaravananDS try to check `Mage_Review_ProductController::postAction()`

The element with the `customfield` key should present in the $data array. `isset($data['customfield'])` should return true.

Comment: Sorry no luck. Not present there.

Comment: @SaravananDS it means that data from your form (template) doesn't reach the request. You should check your form and its sending method. I suppose that field is located outside the form; the request is send by Ajax and data doesn't get to the request parameters during sending. There are misspellings in the title. Can you please leave here the URL to this form or modify your question with the code of this template including form to let us help you.